# How to detect libc name and version in cross-compiler environments?

Tags: c

I have a few cross-compilers on my linux desktop. Some use glibc and some use uclibc (and in future there could be other `libc`s too).

Currently, I can go into their sysroot directories and search for `libc.so` and try to find which file name it points to (for eg. `libc.so` -> `libuClibc-1.0.12.so`) and I fetch their names. But this won't last long if naming changes or if cross-compiler itself changes.

Is there a better/reliable programmatic way of detecting the name and version of the `libc` being used by a target cross compiler? Or are there any introspection tools available to get details about the target ceros

Note: There are a few similar questions here which normally point to `#include <features.h>` file or similar. That works fine if the generated code can also run on the host. But not suitable for cross-compile environments.

So has anyone been able to detect much more reliably?

EDIT: On the off chance someone comes here looking for detecting musl libc specifically, I've [answered another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58177815/how-to-actually-detect-musl-libc/60471114#60471114) on SO that is related to this question.

Comment: You could check for preprocessor macros. For instance, `gcc -dM -E - <<< "#include <features.h>" | grep -iE "(uclibc|glibc)"`.

Comment: @DaBler The only tiny troubles with that solution are: 1) It shows both `glibc` and `uclibc` for a MIPS32-uclibc cross compiler and 2) I have to parse the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To detect the libc name and version at compile time, you can check for preprocessor macros. The following script is just a proof of concept:

```
GCC_FEATURES=$(gcc -dM -E - <<< "#include <features.h>")

if grep -q __UCLIBC__ <<< "${GCC_FEATURES}"; then
    echo "uClibc"
    grep "#define __UCLIBC_MAJOR__" <<< "${GCC_FEATURES}"
    grep "#define __UCLIBC_MINOR__" <<< "${GCC_FEATURES}"
    grep "#define __UCLIBC_SUBLEVEL__" <<< "${GCC_FEATURES}"
elif grep -q __GLIBC__ <<< "${GCC_FEATURES}"; then
    echo "glibc"
    grep "#define __GLIBC__" <<< "${GCC_FEATURES}"
    grep "#define __GLIBC_MINOR__" <<< "${GCC_FEATURES}"
else
    echo "something else"
fi
```

The uClibc test must be done first, since uClibc defines macros to mimic glibc.

Another possibility could be calling `ldd --version` in your cross-compiler environment (the glibc version is in parentheses). But I'm not sure if this works with libraries other than glibc.

Comment: This is roughly what I was looking for. But this trick won't work for musl (https://wiki.musl-libc.org/faq.html). For most parts this is excellent. Thanks.

Comment: Just to add to this, you can test for musl libc by including features.h with _GNU_SOURCE defined and checking if __USE_GNU is defined, as musl libc uses _GNU_SOURCE directly to protect exposing GNU extensions unlike most the other major Linux libc's