# How to check libc version?

Tags: c, cross-compiling, libc

This question is related to [Why does pclose return prematurely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62724531/why-does-pclose-return-prematurely). **I'd like to find out what version of `libc` is used for a cross-compiled executable.** There are limitations, described below, that make the answers at [Check glibc version for a particular gcc compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705660/check-glibc-version-for-a-particular-gcc-compiler) not apply.

- One proposed way to check the `libc` version is to use the `gnu_get_libc_version()` function declared in `gnu/libc-version.h`. My cross-toolchain does not include `libc-version.h`.
- Another proposed solution is to use the `-print-file-name` `gcc` option. This answer in the linked question just flat-out didn't work for me:

```
$ /path/to/toolchains/ARM-cortex-m3-4.4/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc -print-file-name=libc.so
libc.so
$
$ /path/to/toolchains/ARM-cortex-m3-4.4/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc -print-file-name=foo.bar
foo.bar
$ # I really do not have a foo.bar file in existence
```

- Another proposed solution is to just do `ldd --version`. My target platform doesn't have `ldd`:

```
$ ldd
sh: can't execute 'ldd': No such file or directory
```

- Another proposed solution is to look at `__GLIBC__` and `__GLIBC_MINOR__` -- but these also appear to come from `libc-version.h`, which doesn't exist in my cross-toolchain, as described above.

My cross-toolchain seems to only provide `libc.a`, not `libc.so`.
I tried running that `libc.a` through `/path/to/toolchains/ARM-cortex-m3-4.4/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-nm` and `strings` grepping (case-insensitive) for "version" and "libc" but did not find anything that looked like an identifying version.

The last thing I tried was `strings /path/to/toolchains/ARM-cortex-m3-4.4/bin/arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc | grep GLIBC`, which gave me:

```
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.2
GLIBC_2.1
GLIBC_2.0
EGLIBC configuration specifier, serves multilib purposes.
```

But that solution wasn't highly upvoted, and it also has a comment suggesting that it doesn't really give you the version. *I don't really understand this answer or its responding comment, so I don't know what to make of its validity.*

**Question: given all the above, is there any definitive way to determine the libc version used for cross-compiling for this cross-platform?**

Comment: The `strings` thing is most likely just telling you that the compiler executable itself is linked against the (host) glibc.  That wouldn't tell you anything about what the executables it produces do.

Comment: It sounds like maybe your target platform doesn't use glibc at all, but perhaps some entirely unrelated C library, so glibc stuff may not be of any use.  Each implementation of a C library gets to decide for itself how to report its version numbering (if at all); there's no standard interface as far as I know.  So you're going to need to find out what C library you installed and read its documentation.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the effort put into researching this question. A comment on the other question suggests you might be dealing with uclibc. Can you try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50471325/530160) and check if it gives you the correct version?

Comment: @NateEldredge - is the compiler/toolchain completely independent of the `libc`? I thought that because the compiler was (a cross-compiling flavor of) `gcc`, that implied it was a `gnu` toolchain, thereby also including `gnu` `libc`...?

Comment: @StoneThrow: No, the compiler and C library are generally agnostic of one another.  As long as they both obey the correct ABI, any combination is supposed to work.

Comment: You can't "portably" check the version or origin of C implementation. My guess is you use newlib. But why not just navigate to the directory with the system headers and inspect them?

Comment: @KamilCuk - that sounds similar to the suggestion at my other linked question: a commenter there suggested I "look at the files in the cross toolchain's sysroot" -- I think I don't really understand what that means...do you mean literally just look around at various files in that directory-tree and look for a string that has the libc version?

Comment: @NateEldredge - is there a way to determine the "flavor" of `libc`? I.e. if I knew which variant of `libc` it was, perhaps I could look up its documentation on how to get its version. Fwiw, as far as I can tell, the only thing I have to work with is `libc.a`.

Comment: I like the suggestion made on the other question - find the header files and look for identifying comments or macros.  Surely you have those in addition to libc.a, otherwise you can't compile anything anyway.

Comment: To answer your direct question, there is no universal way - every implementation decides for itself what to do.  It's assumed that you are able to remember what software you installed, or that you did it in a way that keeps logs or records (e.g. via your OS package manager).

Comment: In `/path/to/toolchains/ARM-cortex-m3-4.4/` there is most probably an `include` or `usr/include` directory. In that directory there are standard headres `stdef.h` `stdint.h` etc. See at the top of these files - maybe there is a "copyright" section, maybe author information. Research that, browse those files.

Comment: @KamilCuk - I find a variety of copyright references, so it's hard to say which one is "right." One example is `/path/to/toolchains/ARM-cortex-m3-4.4/sysroot/include/stdlib.h` which says copyright "1991-2007, 2009). It sounds like this method - i.e. browsing the header files - is the best approach under the circumstances, thank you.

Comment: @NateEldredge - I'll need to check with the engineers responsible for this toolchain; I think you're right - they ought to have record of what software and versions are used to comprise this toolchain.

Comment: @KamilCuk - in case you have any insight on the problem that spawned this question, please visit https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217220/why-does-pclose-return-prematurely and feel free to comment - my most recent post in that chat-room ties both questions together.

Comment: @NateEldredge - in case you have any insight on the problem that spawned this question, please visit https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217220/why-does-pclose-return-prematurely and feel free to comment - my most recent post in that chat-room ties both questions together.

Comment: Well, from the text `EGLIBC configuration specifier` you may be curious to take a look at [EGLIBC](https://github.com/Xilinx/eglibc).

Comment: @NickODell - that seems to have generated an interesting lead! The script does end up identifying `uClibc`, and version major.minor.sublevel 0.9.30. I'll need to ponder and research this a little more in the context of the other linked question. Are you pretty confident in this script's validity to identify `uClibc`? I'm new to this concept of there being different "variants" of l`ibc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be dealing with a variant of libc other than glibc. There are multiple [different implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library#Implementations) of libc, such as musl or uclibc.

Here's a Bash script which can detect whether your compiler is using glibc or uclibc, and tells you the version if it detects either.

```
GCC_FEATURES=$(gcc -dM -E - <<< "#include <features.h>")

if grep -q __UCLIBC__ <<< "${GCC_FEATURES}"; then
    echo "uClibc"
    grep "#define __UCLIBC_MAJOR__" <<< "${GCC_FEATURES}"
    grep "#define __UCLIBC_MINOR__" <<< "${GCC_FEATURES}"
    grep "#define __UCLIBC_SUBLEVEL__" <<< "${GCC_FEATURES}"
elif grep -q __GLIBC__ <<< "${GCC_FEATURES}"; then
    echo "glibc"
    grep "#define __GLIBC__" <<< "${GCC_FEATURES}"
    grep "#define __GLIBC_MINOR__" <<< "${GCC_FEATURES}"
else
    echo "something else"
fi
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50471325/530160).)

If you're using musl, unfortunately this script will report "something else." There's no way to detect musl with a preprocessor macro, and [this is intentional](https://wiki.musl-libc.org/faq.html).