# Inconsistency with %hhu format specifier in C printf function?

Tags: c, codeblocks, tcc

As far as I had understood it, the %hhu format specifier should have the range of an unsigned char. However, in some compilers I test it in, it seems to have the range of an unsigned short instead. Is there a reason for this?

I tried using %hhu to print, for instance, 65535. I would expect this to print 255 on the assumption the value would be cast to an unsigned char. However in CodeBlocks and Tiny C Compiler, I instead get 65535. If I instead try to print 65536, it prints 0, as I would have expected if I had instead used %hu (with one h).

In OnlineGDB, however, I get the behaviour I would have expected.

Comment: It's likely a bug in the runtime libraries — the `hh` modifier is a more recent addition to the standard (C99, not C90, IIRC).  So it is more likely to be overlooked and/or misimplemented.

Comment: @entropicdecay, for reference, please report the versions of the errant compilers.

Comment: GCC version 5.1.0 and Tiny C Compiler 0.9.27

Comment: GCC is a compiler only and doesn't include the standard library / runtime, so you can't blame GCC for problems with printf.  Rather, find out the version of the standard library you are using (e.g. glibc on Linux systems).  Tiny C may be similar, I'm not sure.  (That said, why are you using an eight-year-old version of GCC?  The latest version is 13.1.)

Comment: If it's using glibc then see this: [Check glibc version for a particular gcc compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9705660/995714). Also [How to check libc version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62732447/995714)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be using glibc. But I'm not certain.

Answer (score 1):

With `*printf()`, `"%hh"`:

> ... Specifies that a following b, d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a `signed char` or `unsigned char` argument (the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to `signed char` or `unsigned char` before printing); ...  C23dr § 7.23.6.1 7

It is reasonable in suspecting an error when values outside the range of `unsigned char` are printed.

[Edit]

On-the-other-hand, `"hh"` is specified to use with a `signed char` or `unsigned char` argument.  Since OP did not do that, the result is *undefined behavior* (UB).

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined. § 7.23.6.1 9

Comment: UCHAR_MAX is 255 as it should be...

Comment: If the implementation works for any `unsigned char` value passed for `%hhu`, I would say it conforms to the standard, and it does not matter what happens when any other value is passed. The standard says the value is converted from `int` to an `unsigned char`, but that is for an `unsigned char` value converted to `int`. If a program passes some other value for `%hhu`, it has violated the requirement to pass an appropriate argument, before any conversion to `unsigned char` occurs, and the standard does not define the behavior.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Fair point.  I'll go with that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In that case, do the `h` and `hh` length modifiers have any useful purpose, or is their only purpose to allow more UB?

Comment: @IanAbbott: The standard is unclear about passing `signed char` (or signed `char`) for `%hhu`; it lumps `signed char` and `unsigned char` together with “or” in a paragraph about “b, d, i, o, u, x, or X” without giving any distinctions about which goes with which. If `signed char` may be used with `%hhu`, then `%hhu` must work with, for example, −1 (producing only “ff”, not “ffffffff”) but is not required to work with −1024 (given an eight-bit `char`).